# Eclipse Organize Packages into Folder Hierarchy

Tags: java, eclipse, file-organization

I have a bunch of packages in an Eclipse project they have names like:
edu.xxx.proj.app
edu.xxx.proj.demo
edu.xxx.proj.utils
Is there a way in Eclipse to automatically collapse them into a folder structure? I would like them to be as follows on the workbench:

```
edu__
     |_xxx__
            |_proj__
                    |_app
                    |_demo
                    |_utils
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Click the little down pointing triangle in the package manager and go to "package presentation".  From there select "hierarchal" and that should take care of it.

Comment: I found the triangle in the upper right corner of the package manager.